# Accessing the indexedDB SQLite file for user local download

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Is there any way to programmatically provide the user a way to download a snapshot of an indexedDB database as a form of backup or historical results, and restore it to the page at a later time?

I've been extracting the data out of the database into a giant blob and downloading it as a text file, and then reading it back in slices to write to the correct object stores. The reading in does not consume a lot of RAM because each slice uses the same variable's memory allocation; but writing it out consumes much more RAM since each piece is held in an array as a blob before that array of small blobs is joined into/reduced to a single giant blob for download.

If I understand correctly, the SQLite file is a flat file on the local disk in a segment appropriated to the browser. Can it not be downloaded to disk by user action, or written to another database as a file? It seems odd to have to extract the data to write it as a flat text file when it already exists in that form on the disk.

This is to be done in an extension; so, extension API methods would be great.

Thank you.